# argparse flag to skip positional args

Tags: python, argparse

I have a script which normally requires a positional argument: `some-script POS`. However, when the "--version" flag is present, I would like to be able to "waive" the positional arg requirement: `some-script --version`.

Is there a proper way to do this within the argparse framework?

I can optionally use `"--version" in sys.argv`, but I would like to be able to use argparse.

Comment: What's supposed to happen with `version`?  Print a message and exit (like `help`), or set some values in `args` (e.g. 'store_true')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a [`version` action](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#action) that makes this possible:

```
parser.add_argument('--version', action='version', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to make the positional argument optional by setting `nargs='?'` and instead raise an error in your code if it's not present. For example:

```
parser.add_argument('POSITIONAL', dest='positional', nargs='?')
...
if parsed.positional is None:
    print('Positional argument "POSITIONAL" is required')
    sys.exit(1)
```

Comment: unfortunately, in my case the positional argument is required, and I'm counting on argparse to catch this and throw an error if it is not provided. so I cannot make it optional. also, this won't scale if one has multiple required positional arguments or other complex logic